# Как создать несколько массивов объектов на основе одного массива объектов?

Tags: javascript

Есть массив вида:

```
const arr = [
    {
      id: '0'
    },
    {
      id: '0.0'
    },
    {
      id: '0.1'
    },
    {
      id: '0.2'
    },
    {
      id: '0.3'
    },
    {
      id: '1'
   },
    {
      id: '1.0'
    },
    {
      id: '1.1'
    },
    {
      id: '2'
    },
    {
      id: '2.0'
    },
    {
      id: '2.1'
    },
    {
      id: '2.2'
    },
  ...
  ]
```

Как из него получить несколько массивов вида?

```
const result0 = [
    {
      id: '0'
    },
    {
      id: '0.0'
    },
    {
      id: '0.1'
    },
    {
      id: '0.2'
    },
    {
      id: '0.3'
    }
  ]

  const result1 = [
    {
      id: '1'
    },
    {
      id: '1.0'
    },
    {
      id: '1.1'
    }
  ]
  const result2 = [
    {
      id: '2'
    },
    {
  id: '2.0'
    },
    {
      id: '2.1'
    },
    {
      id: '2.2'
    },
  ]

const resultN = [
  ...
]
```

Comment: Зачем такое поведение нужно?

Comment: и чем определяется количество в каждой переменной?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Судя по всему, числом до точки в id

Comment: @LaukhinAndrey да, но всё ещё не ясно почему это нужно в каждую переменную совать. а не сделать, например, массив с массивами